# How can I control two independent audio players in JS?

Tags: javascript, audio

I have the following code for a simple audio player with a balance controller.

How can I create two players that I can control independently? (so that each pan button will apply only for the suitable player).

What's the easiest way to do this?

```
<html>
<button onclick="playPause()">play/pause</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="setBalance(-1)">Left</button>
<button onclick="setBalance(0)">Center</button>
<button onclick="setBalance(+1)">Right</button>
<script>
const audioElement = new Audio("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3");
audioElement.crossOrigin = "anonymous"; // cross-origin - if file is stored on remote server

const audioContext = new AudioContext();

const audioSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

const volumeNodeL = new GainNode(audioContext);
const volumeNodeR = new GainNode(audioContext);

volumeNodeL.gain.value = 2;
volumeNodeR.gain.value = 2;

const channelsCount = 2; // or read from: 'audioSource.channelCount'

const splitterNode = new ChannelSplitterNode(audioContext, { numberOfOutputs: channelsCount });
const mergerNode = new ChannelMergerNode(audioContext, { numberOfInputs: channelsCount });

audioSource.connect(splitterNode);

splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeL, 0); // connect OUTPUT channel 0
splitterNode.connect(volumeNodeR, 1); // connect OUTPUT channel 1

volumeNodeL.connect(mergerNode, 0, 0); // connect INPUT channel 0
volumeNodeR.connect(mergerNode, 0, 1); // connect INPUT channel 1

mergerNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

let isPlaying;
function playPause() {
  // check if context is in suspended state (autoplay policy)
  if (audioContext.state === 'suspended') {
    audioContext.resume();
  }

  isPlaying = !isPlaying;
  if (isPlaying) {
    audioElement.play();
  } else {
    audioElement.pause();
  }
}

function setBalance(val) {
  volumeNodeL.gain.value = 1 - val;
  volumeNodeR.gain.value = 1 + val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are not better if using a panner node? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/createStereoPanner

Comment: @fdcpp What's the advantage of this way?

Comment: It looks like you’re just trying to create a panner, so it avoids you reinventing the wheel.